# Create bash completion script to autocomplete paths after is-equal sign?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, chrome

I want to create a bash completion script which recognises arguments of the form `--arg` and `--some-arg=file`.

After reading [this tutorial](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) and some examples in `/usr/share/bash_completion/completions/`, I've written the following script (to save time at typing some flags with Chromium):

```
_chromium() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    # Some interesting options
    opts="
--disable-web-security
--easy-off-store-extension-install
--incognito
--load-extension=
--pack-extension=
--pack-extension-key=
--user-data-dir=
"
    # Handle --xxxxxx=file
    if [[ ${cur} == "--"*"=" ]] ; then
        # Removed failures (is my logic OK?)
        return 0
    fi

    # Handle other options
    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _chromium chromium
```

I saved it to `~/bash_completions/chromium`, and created a symlink using `sudo ln -s ~/bash_completions/chromium /usr/share/bash_completion/completions/chromium`.
Then I loaded it using `. /usr/share/bash_completions/completions/chromium`.

Now, I'm experiencing two problems:

- `chromium --u<TAB>` expands to `chromium --user-data-dir=<SPACE>` (I don't want the space).
- Paths (directories and files) are not completed any more.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Is switching to zsh an option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the solution to both problems!

1. To not append a space, use the `nospace` option. This can be done in two ways:

   - Pass it to the `complete`:
     `complete -o nospace -F _chromium chromium`
   - Use the `compopt` built-in:
     `compopt -o nospace` (to enable the option)
     `compopt +o nospace` (to disable the option)

   I found it in the Bash documentation at gnu.org, [8.7 Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).
2. Completion of files.

   - [peterph suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55520/create-bash-completion-script-to-autocomplete-paths-after-is-equal-sign/55549#55549) to use the `-f` flag with `compgen`. I followed that advice, and implemented it as `COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f "$cur") )`. This worked fine, until I tried to complete a path containing spaces.
     On Stack Overflow, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652492/bash-autocompletion-how-to-pass-this-array-to-compgen-without-significant-whit/11482571#11482571) which recommends manual creation of the completion list (without using `compgen`). This approach worked fine.
   - Use the `filenames` option to tell Readline that the compspec generates filenames, so it can:

     - perform any filename-specific processing (like adding a slash to directory names, quoting special characters, or suppressing trailing spaces)
     - use different colors to indicate file type (with `colored-stats` enabled)

With aid of [Bash's string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) (to expand `~` and deal with spaces), I constructed a bash completion scripts which meets all criteria stated in the question.

```
_chromium() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    # Some interesting options
    opts="
--disable-web-security
--easy-off-store-extension-install
--incognito
--load-extension=
--pack-extension=
--pack-extension-key=
--user-data-dir=
"
    # Handle --xxxxxx=
    if [[ ${prev} == "--"* && ${cur} == "=" ]] ; then
        compopt -o filenames
        COMPREPLY=(*)
        return 0
    fi
    # Handle --xxxxx=path
    if [[ ${prev} == '=' ]] ; then
        # Unescape space
        cur=${cur//\\ / }
        # Expand tilder to $HOME
        [[ ${cur} == "~/"* ]] && cur=${cur/\~/$HOME}
        # Show completion if path exist (and escape spaces)
        compopt -o filenames
        local files=("${cur}"*)
        [[ -e ${files[0]} ]] && COMPREPLY=( "${files[@]// /\ }" )
        return 0
    fi

    # Handle other options
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- "${cur}") )
    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} == 1 && ${COMPREPLY[0]} != "--"*"=" ]] ; then
        # If there's only one option, without =, then allow a space
        compopt +o nospace
    fi
    return 0
}
complete -o nospace -F _chromium chromium
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot. You've saved a lot of my time. I used `-f` switch for file path completion, but it does not complete the `/` char if it is a directory... it is a small thing though.

Answer (score 1):

To complete filenames try passing `-f` to `compgen`.

I'm afraid you won't be able to get rid of the spaces after the options, since that's how completion works - once it finds a unique match, it completes it completely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `-f`. I tried it, but it does not correctly deal with spaces: The path `/tmp/foo bar` results in two completion entries `/tmp/foo` and `bar`. About the unwanted `--arg=<SPACE>`: I have found the solution to that, and posted it in[the answer below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55520/create-bash-completion-script-to-autocomplete-paths-after-is-equal-sign/55622#55622).