# Tab completion after equality sign in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

How do I get bash to autocomplete when pressing TAB after an equality sign (=)? E.g. starting Abaqus, I use the command line

```
abaqus job=
```

and would like to be able to press TAB after '=' and get a list of files. Right now, I can insert a space after the '=', press tab to get a list of files, choose file and then remove the space.

I know about bash completion, but that way to much involved except if someone has an example of exactly how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop bash being too smart restricting completion options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288478/how-to-stop-bash-being-too-smart-restricting-completion-options)

Comment: @muru the answer to the purported dupe is way off: the user should either fix/define a `cmake` compspec, disable the programmable completion, or add back `=` to `COMP_WORDBREAKS` if it isn't already there (highly unlikely). There are a lot of other Qs from people fighting with bash's programmable completion, you'll have no problem finding a more suitable dupe ;-)

Comment: @mosvy alt-/ still does work though, without all that fiddling.

Comment: @muru alt-/ is awkward and does not work when using vi mode. Tab is in the muscle memory, and people want to press Tab, not do finger gymnastics.

Comment: [This seems to be related.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55520/313715)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either go learn how to fiddle with bash's [Programmable Completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) (not for the faint of heart ;-)) or just **disable it** with

```
shopt -u progcomp
```

That you will get the classical `readline(3)` command / variable / filename completion back [1].

If the programmable completion is already disabled and `=<Tab>` still doesn't work, you should check the `COMP_WORDBREAKS` variable and add the `=` character to it if it isn't already included.

[1] for me the right fix on debian has always been

```
apt-get remove --purge bash-completion
```

which will uproot it completely, and prevent it from surreptitiously coming back.

Comment: Thank you! The `shopt -u progcomp` was exactly what I was looking for.